# Deleting from a paired list

Tags: scala

I have a function that removes one list `y` from  list `x`.  The precondition is that the occurrence list `y` is a subset of `x` - any character appearing in `y` must  appear in `x`, and its frequency in `y` must be <= its frequency in `x`.

The resulting value is an occurrence - meaning it is sorted and has no zero-entries.

This is my original code. This was for the Scala progfun assignment, now I'm just curious as to what the right answer was.

```
type Occurrences = List[(Char, Int)]

def subtract(x: Occurrences, y: Occurrences): Occurrences = x filterNot (y contains)
```

It has to pass the following unit tests.

Test 1

```
 test("subtract: lard - r") {
    val lard = List(('a', 1), ('d', 1), ('l', 1), ('r', 1))
    val r = List(('r', 1))
    val lad = List(('a', 1), ('d', 1), ('l', 1))
    assert(subtract(lard, r) === lad)
  }
```

Test 2

```
// subtract: jimmy - my
List((i,1), (j,1), (m,1), (y,0)) did not equal List((i,1), (j,1), (m,1))
```

Test 3

```
//subtract: ok - ok
List((k,0), (o,0)) did not equal List()
```

Test 4

```
//subtract: abba - abba
List((a,0), (b,0)) did not equal List()
```

Test 5

```
//subtract: assessment - assess
```

Comment: This is from the Coursera Scala course.

Comment: From your tests I would say that you need more than filtering only. Your filter just removes all pairs in x that are *exactly* in y (e.g. `('r',1) == ('r', 1)`). But tests 2, 3, 4 suggests that you first want to map `x` to decrement each pair number of the corresponding number in `y` for the same "key". Then you can remove from the mapped list those elements whose number is `0`. I won't write the code since this could violate Coursera's agreement.

Comment: Coursera have a great forum for this course, I find it very useful. By the way, the hard deadline for this assignment is not over yet I think

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to strip elements the left of which equals with the left of any element of y,  a following code does so.

```
def subtract(x: Occurrences, y: Occurrences): Occurrences = 
  x filterNot (y.map(_._1) contains _._1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the assignment correctly, it is necessary to subtract the counts. My attempt would be something like that:

```
def subtract(x: Occurrences, y: Occurrences): Occurrences = {
  val my = y.toMap
  x.map(occ => (occ._1, occ._2 - (my.get(occ._1) getOrElse 0) ))
   .filter(_._2 > 0)
}
```